# Razor view errors while Migrating from core 2.2 to 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, asp.net-core-3.1

After doing the general upgrade steps for the migration. My razor had 100's of errors suddenly after removing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All. These error were not consistent, these were general compiler errors.

Some combination of

- IDE1007 C# The name does not exist in the current context.
- CS0111 C# Type already defines a member called with the same parameter types
- CS0538 C# in explicit interface declaration is not an interface
- CS0116 C# A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields
  or methods
- CS8107 C# Feature is not available in C# 7.0. Please use
  language version 9.0 or greater.

Just all over the place stuff, and this was all working perfectly in 2.2

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. What I found was that we had few places in the code where we were using @ inside a razor block, this used to work fine but breaks in core 3.1. I am assuming that the process of generating the classes by Razor SDK was failing because I was also getting errors in index.g.cshtml.cs.

We probably had this issue in 5 files at most but we were getting 500+ build errors. Very frustrating, so adding this answer because I was not able to find any similar answer anywhere.

Example of bad code, notice the extra @ inside {}.

```
@{ var replacements = new string[] { @Model.TotalItemsInCart.ToString() };}
```